# Call to undefined function time_nanosleep()

Tags: php, macports

I have installed php/apache (version 5.3.8) via MacPorts, and I am getting the error:
Call to undefined function time_nanosleep()

According to the manual:
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.time-nanosleep.php
this function has been built into php since version 5, and for Windows 5.3. I'm on a Mac, but in either case I should be good.

Is there some magic you have to do to enable this on MacPorts? Is there some extra package you have to install? I'm definitely confused on this one. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [a bug in PHP](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71672) that was introduced between PHP 5.3.3 and 5.3.4. I have [fixed it in MacPorts in php5 @5.3.8_1](https://trac.macports.org/changeset/85066); run `sudo port selfupdate` and `sudo port upgrade php5` to receive the fix.